# How to get value by key from AmazonMWS OrderList Object

Tags: php, arrays, object, amazon-mws

```
AmazonOrder Object
(
    [data:protected] => Array
       (
        [AmazonOrderId] => OrderId
        [SellerOrderId] => SellerOrederId
        [PurchaseDate] => 2018-10-04T06:38:20.238Z
       )
)
```

This is the object i get when pull data from Amazon MWS Orderlist Api, 
I am unable to access AmazonOrderId in this object how do i get only AmazonOrderId in loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [source of MWS PHP SDK](https://developer.amazonservices.com/doc/orders/orders/v20130901/php.html/140-9949880-9873928) these fields have accessor methods like `::getAmazonOrderId()` or `::getSellerOrderId()` , so try to access them with `$object->getAmazonOrderId()`